# WP oEmbed for unsupported service (e.g. kubity.com)?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, oembed

I'm trying to get kubity to embed via the `wp_oembed_add_provider()` function in the functions.php doc.

```
<?php 
// Register Kubity as an oEmbed provider
function kubity_oembed() {

    wp_oembed_add_provider( '#https?://(www\.)?kubity.com/p/.*#i', 'https://www.kubity.com/embed/', true );

}
add_action( 'init', 'kubity_oembed' );
?>
```

My question is whether I need to make my own json document and specify thumbnails and so on for this and if so, where would I put the URL for the JSON output?

**About this Task**:
* Client is set on only using Kubity to show their embedded objects on their wordpress site. 
* The embed code from kubity is an iframe.
* The theme of the website has an "portfolio" page which allows you to embed youtube/vimeo (basically anything that oembed standard protocols allow), into part of a slideshow/gallery with the page content.

**Note**: I've contacted the support providers for kubity but they've not got round to replying in a few days.  I figured I'd put my hand to making it work without their support.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried various attempts of putting my own local php json oembed output in order to structure the embeded data.  However, I found the documentation became fruitless on this one, I wasn't clear how the provider and the response was to work.

I have worked around this with an if statement around the original oembed variable in the template.

N.B. this theme has a custom slideshow for posts with option for embedded videos, I was hoping to modify the oembed to handle custom urls but came short.

```
 if ( !empty( $video_url ) ) {  // existing code

    //detect if it is kubity URL
    if ( strpos( $video_url, 'kubity') !== false) {
        //get the serial of the attached url. 
        $kubitySerial = substr( strrchr( $video_url, '/' ), 1 );

    }
}
```

From this I can use the `$kubitySerial` in order to serialize the item into a friendly iframe embed url for Kubity.